# Object recognition from webcam images

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic, webcam, object-detection

I'm trying to make a Poor Man's Kinect. In order to do this, I'm getting frames from the webcam and I need to recognise whether an array of pixels has moved, including some error margin. In order to do this, on a new image I need to check for each pixel if it's part of an object and for that to be true, i check their neighbours (left, up, right, down) and whether their RGB values subtracted from the initial pixel are smaller than a fixed value, the pixel is contained in that object.

Is this a good approach or is there a better algorithm for this?

Comment: What are you implementing this in ? Cheapest version of motion detection is to do basic background subtraction: store the 1st frame(clear background) at the start of the program, then do image differencing between that frame the current. What isn't black is moving. Similarly you could do frame differencing: compare the current frame with the previous frame and look at the result of the absolute difference operation on the two. Still, this is basic motion detection and you're asking about object detection. Have a look at SURF, SIFT algorithms. OpenCV implements those already.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in Python, but any algorithm written in another programming language can help me. OpenCV sounds like a great idea and I'm willing to try it.

Comment: OpenCV comes with Python bindings (cv2.*) but be aware that not all c++ functionalities are available in Python so first check what algorithm suits your task best and also if it's in the Python bindings. I also found [this project](https://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/) on google but haven't tried it myself. another one that looks appealing is [simpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/). Baftă Ștefan :)